# TCL parsing a file

Tags: tcl

I would like to store the headers vdd, vddpll, ..etc as keys and associated column entries as values.
From the below example, would like to read each column and store against first entry in the column.

```
vdd -> ON ON OFF OFF
vddpll -> ON OFF ON OFFF
```

...etc

```
create_pst top_pst -supplies      {vdd   vddpll vdd_NWELL vdd33  gnd     gnd_PWELL}
add_pst_state state1  -pst top_pst -state    {ON     ON     ON        ON    gnd_on  gnd_on}
add_pst_state state2  -pst top_pst -state    {ON     OFF    ON        ON    gnd_on  gnd_on}
add_pst_state state3  -pst top_pst -state    {OFF    ON     ON        ON    gnd_on  gnd_on}
add_pst_state state4  -pst top_pst -state    {OFF    OFF    ON        ON    gnd_on  gnd_on}
```

```
set fp [open "test.upf" r]
set i 0

while {[gets $fp data] >= 0} {

if {[regexp "create_pst" $data match]} {
set supplies_row [split_line $data]
set supply_names [lrange $supplies_row 3 end]
for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $supply_names]} {incr j} {
set power_name [lindex $supply_names $j]
set power_and_state($power_name) {}
}

if {[regexp "add_pst_state" $data match]} {
set state_row [split_line $data]
set supply_state [lrange $state_row 5 end]
for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $supply_state]} {incr j} {
set power_name [lindex $supply_names $j]
lappend power_and_state($power_name) [lindex $supply_state $j]
}
}

proc split_line {data} {
set upf_entries1 [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $data]
set entries1 [regsub "{" $upf_entries1 ""]
set entries2 [regsub "}" $entries1 ""]
set entries3 [regsub -all {\-} $entries2 ""]
set entries4 [regsub -all {\\} $entries3 ""]
return $entries4 
}
}
close $fp
```

I am expecting power_and_state array contain all the keys vdd, vddpll..etc and the associated entries are stored in a list assigned to the keys.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> I am expecting power_and_state array contain all the keys vdd,
>   vddpll..etc and the associated entries are stored in a list assigned
>   to the keys.

I think your "data feed" matches very nicely Tcl's native syntax, so there is no need to take a detour via regular expressions. Just piggyback onto Tcl as much as possible. One straightforward way could be as follows:

```
set data {create_pst top_pst -supplies {vdd vddpll vdd_NWELL vdd33 gnd gnd_PWELL}
add_pst_state state1 -pst top_pst -state {ON ON ON ON gnd_on gnd_on}
add_pst_state state2 -pst top_pst -state {ON OFF ON ON gnd_on gnd_on}
add_pst_state state3 -pst top_pst -state {OFF ON ON ON gnd_on gnd_on}
add_pst_state state4 -pst top_pst -state {OFF OFF ON ON gnd_on gnd_on}}

proc create_pst {name args} {
    global $name
    set opts [dict create {*}$args]
    set $name [dict create {*}"[join [dict get $opts -supplies] " {} "] {}"]
    return
}

proc add_pst_state {name args} {
    set opts [dict create {*}$args]
    set pst [dict get $opts -pst]
    global $pst
    set state [dict get $opts -state]
    foreach k [dict keys [set $pst]] v $state {
       dict lappend $pst $k $v
    }
    return
}

eval $data

puts $top_pst
```

### Some explanatory remarks

- Two procs `create_pst` and `add_pst_state` match the "input statements".
- There is a simple protocol between these two procs, based on a global `dict` named after `create_pst` first arg.
- `create_pst` will initialise the global `dict` with all the keys, to preserve their order.
- later calls to `add_pst_state` build on the preserved order, by simply looping (`foreach`) over the ordered keys.
- there are some helper `dict` involved, mainly to process the non-positional arguments to the two procs (`-supplies`, `-pst`, `-state`).

Comment: I'd have used `eval` instead of `try`.

Comment: Hello Donal, Thank you for your prompt response. I am completely new to tcl environment. I copied the code as it is and ran, it's failing with the below error message.                                        
    add_pst_state: command not found
    add_pst_state: command not found
    add_pst_state: command not found
    add_pst_state: command not found
    proc: command not found
    global: command not found
    return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
    syntax error near unexpected token `}'
   `}'

Comment: "copied and ran"? this is too unspecific, I am afraid. As a starter: Save the script in a separate file (`myscript.tcl`) and run from the CLI: `tclsh myscript.tcl`. You should probably jump-start yourself before working on your task at hand, by looking at the [Tcl tutorial](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).

Comment: @mrcalvin Sorry, I should have been more specific. Thanks for the tutorial.  My understanding is that the top_pst should have the vdd,vddpll..etc  keys and the other information as values.   All the entries from add_pst_state are stored in a single list instead of  individual lists corresponding to the supplies keys.
    vdd{}vddpll{}vdd_NWELL{}vdd33{}gnd{}gnd_PWELL {ON ON OFF OFF} {} {ON ON ON gnd_on gnd_on OFF ON ON gnd_on gnd_on ON ON ON gnd_on gnd_on OFF ON ON gnd_on gnd_on}.

Comment: When this is the output you get from running some script, then it is not exactly the one I posted. This is what you get when you do 1:1 as I hinted at: `vdd {ON ON OFF OFF} vddpll {ON OFF ON OFF} vdd_NWELL {ON ON ON ON} vdd33 {ON ON ON ON} gnd {gnd_on gnd_on gnd_on gnd_on} gnd_PWELL {gnd_on gnd_on gnd_on gnd_on}`

Comment: The only way I can reproduce what you get is by turning `" {} "` in the `join` call into `"{}"` (2 whitespaces removed). Most likely, your practise of copy&pasting is destructive. You must pay closer attention to such details.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. I understand the issue now. I didn't pay attention to the white spaces.